# Auto Detect Silent Switches for EXE

Tags: powershell, scripting, installation

In our environment, we are trying to automate the process of Unattended/Silent Installation for EXE's.
I would like to know, is there a way to auto-detect the silent switches for executables. Is there some way to determine if an EXE has some sort of unattended install support and, if so, get the right argument so I can pass it to the file when I run it? or to get the installer information like if its Installshield, Innosetup or Installanywhere?

Thank You

Comment: Please read [this](http://unattended.sourceforge.net/installers.php) helpful article on Internet first

Comment: Tagging on to what Kate Orlova gave you. This is not a PowerShell question, so to is off topic and moved to PowerUser. Anyway, the vendor of the exe must provide you with this information in the product docs or it's online counterpart, or the vendor must provide a switch on the exe which shows you what params it can take. If neither of the two exist, it's assumption that it does not provide it. You are asking if there is a way to disassemble an Exe to get at its internals, that is a topic for a far different forum.